# Using Apache Camel and Spring, can I build uri using properties?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have created my own component and I want to do something similar to this:

```
<camel:camelContext id="camel1">
    <camel:route>
        <camel:from uri="mysch://realthing?network=${network}" id="testEndpoint"/>
```

I want ${network} to come from a properties file (using Spring properties placeholder):

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:test.properties"/>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this FAQ
http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-spring-property-placeholder-with-camel-xml.html